# aero snap left and right in metacity ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: shortcut-keys, 14.10, window-manager, gnome-classic, metacity

I managed to install Gnome classic Metacity on Ubuntu 14.10 using this:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

I can user the `Super` (Windows) key to maximize and restore the windows with the `Up` and `Down` arrows.

I would also like to have the Aero Snap effect with `Super+left` and `Super+right`, ideally also having it working with my external screen plugged.

I want this to work with Metacity, I would rather have it done in a quick and dirty way than having to move to something different than Metacity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You can use
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>