# Ubuntu 14.10 Aero snap in two screen horizontal setup?

Tags: multiple-monitors, screen, 14.10, metacity

I managed to get [Aero snap left and right working in metacity Ubuntu 14.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/566288/17702) and now I would like to come up with the correct `winctrl` commands so that I can mimic the same effect on a two screen setup, where the two screens are placed horizontally next to each other as in the image below. I want this to work on Metacity (GNOME classic), I am not willing to move to other window managers at all, since I know some of them have these capabilities built-in already. So this is a question to try and find an answer for the Metacity GNOME classic environment specifically:

[image]

What I want is to extend my current `winctrl` commands. They currently work by using up half the total width of the screen either left or right of the total screen length. Typing `Super_L+left` will make the active window use the left half, and typing `Super_L+right` will make the active window use the right half size of the total horizontal pixels.

```
[hpenvy15 ~] $ cat > ~/bin/left.sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 0.1 && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,0,0,`xwininfo -root | grep Width | awk '{ print (($2/2))}'`,`xwininfo -root | grep Height | awk '{ print $2 }'`
^C
[hpenvy15 ~] $ cat > ~/bin/right.sh
#!/bin/bash
sleep 0.1 && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz && wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,`xwininfo -root | grep Width | awk '{ print (($2/2)+5) ",0," (($2/2)) }'`,`xwininfo -root | grep Height | awk '{ print $2 }'`
^C
```

In the new setup with two screens, I have 1920+1920 pixels wide. The ideal width of a window is half of 1920, this is 1920/2=960. I would like for the new `left` and `right` commands to calculate where is the window currently found, then if `left` is typed, to go to the nearest 960-wide pixels block, in any of the 4 blocks present in the two screen, 1920+1920 configuration, but also work to the nearest 960-wide block in the one screen 1920 configuration. A diagram is shown below:

This is the configuration when I have the external screen in 1 and 2,
and the laptop screen in 3 and 4. Currently, clicking `Super_L+left`
would move the window to the TotalWidth/2 left half of the screen,
which would be too big, going to 1+2.

I would want the first `left` command to move it to pane 3, then the
next `left` command to move it to 2, then the next one to move it to
1.

```
   +-------------------++-------------------++-------------------++-------------------+
   |                   ||                   ||                   || +------------+    |
   |                   ||                   ||                   || |            |    |
   |                   ||                   ||           <-------++-+            |    |
   |                   ||                   ||                   || |            |    |
   |         1         ||         2         ||         3         || |       4    |    |
   |                   ||                   ||                   || |            |    |
   |                   ||                   ||                   || +------------+    |
   |                   ||                   ||                   ||                   |
   |                   ||                   ||                   ||                   |
   +-------------------++-------------------++-------------------++-------------------+
```

This is the configuration when I have only the laptop screen in two halves of 960 pixels wide.

Currently, clicking `Super_L+right` would move the window to the
TotalWidth/2 right half of the screen, which corresponds to number 4.

```
   +-------------------++-------------------+
   | +------------+    ||                   |
   | |            |    ||                   |
   | |            |    ||                   |
   | |            |----++--->               |
   | |       3    |    ||         4         |
   | |            |    ||                   |
   | |            |    ||                   |
   | +------------+    ||                   |
   |                   ||                   |
   +-------------------++-------------------+
```

This is the output of `wmctrl` when the two screens are on:

```
wmctrl -d
0  * DG: 3840x1080  VP: 0,0  WA: 0,0 3840x1080  Workspace 1
1  - DG: 3840x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,0 3840x1080  Workspace 2
2  - DG: 3840x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,0 3840x1080  Workspace 3
3  - DG: 3840x1080  VP: N/A  WA: 0,0 3840x1080  Workspace 4
```

And this is the output of `xrandr` also when the two screens are on:

```
[hpenvy15 ~] $ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080      60.1*+   59.9     40.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9     30.0     25.0     24.0     30.0     24.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1366x768       59.8  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1280x720       60.0     50.0     59.9  
   1440x576i      50.1  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   1440x480i      60.1     60.1  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   720x576        50.0  
   720x480        60.0     59.9  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the script below on Ubuntu (Gnome) Classic and Gnome Flashback (Metacity) 14.04. The "mixed" application of `xdotool` and `wmctrl` was necessary because of some peculiarities I ran into writing the script for Metacity.

#### The solution

As a result of the fact that I wanted the script to:

- determine which is the left/right screen
- calculate both monitor's resolutions
- also work fine if the two screens are of different resolutions (and calculate both the positions and the targeted sizes of the windows)
- work fine if either a second screen is connected or not

-- the script got a bit more extensive then I foresaw.

#### What it does:

*If a second monitor is connected:*
It works pretty much as you describe:

- it divides the two screens in four areas, each area is half the size of the screen it is located on (as said, also with different resolutions)
- running it with the option "left" or "right":

  - it moves the window to the area on the left/right of the window
  - re-sizes it horizontally to half the size of the *targeted* screen
  - maximizes the window vertically

*If no second monitor is connected:*
It works in the traditional way:

- run with the option "left", it maximizes the front-most window vertically on the left half of the screen
- run with the option "right", it maximizes the front-most window vertically on the right half of the screen

#### How to use it

- Install both `xdotool` and `wmctrl`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install wmctrl
  sudo apt-get install xdotool
  ```
- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `aero.py` run it by the command(s)

  ```
  python3 /path/to/aero.py left
  python3 /path/to/aero.py right
  ```

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

move = sys.argv[1]

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd]).decode("utf-8")
def execute(cmd):
    subprocess.call(["/bin/bash", "-c", cmd])

# screen resolutions ("raw")  
wds = [s for s in get("xrandr").split() if s.endswith("+0")]
# x-res left/right)
left = [scr.split("x")[0] for scr in wds if scr.endswith("+0+0")]
right = [scr.split("x")[0] for scr in wds if not scr.endswith("+0+0")]
# x-positions areas
left_pos = [0, int(int(left[0])/2), int(left[0])]
right_pos = [int(int(left[0])+int(right[0])/2)] if len(right) != 0 else []
x_positions = left_pos+right_pos
# frontmost window pos
frontmost =get("printf 0x%x "+get("xdotool getwindowfocus").strip())
frontmost = frontmost[:2]+"0"+frontmost[2:]
f_data = [l.split() for l in get("wmctrl -lG").splitlines() if frontmost in l][0][:6]
curr_pos = int(f_data[2])
area = len([x for x in x_positions if x <= curr_pos])
if move == "left":
    i = area-2; target_pos = x_positions[i] if i >= 0 else 0 
elif move == "right":
    i = area; target_pos = x_positions[area] if area < len(x_positions) else x_positions[-1]
if i >= 2:
    perc = int((100*(x_positions[-1]-x_positions[-2])/sum([int(it) for it in left+right])))
else:
    perc = int((100*(x_positions[1]-x_positions[0])/sum([int(it) for it in left+right])))
# execute actions
cmd1 = "wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -b remove,maximized_vert,maximized_horz"
cmd2 = "wmctrl -ir "+f_data[0]+" -e 0,"+str(target_pos)+","+"30,300,300"
cmd3 = "xdotool windowsize $(xdotool getactivewindow) "+str(perc)+"% 100%"
for cmd in [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3]:
    execute(cmd)
```

Also posted on [gist.gisthub](https://gist.github.com/Jacob-Vlijm/e08a6f34c9789cf38ad8) (latest version)