# How can I add semi-maximize right/left in Gnome Flashback Metacity? (14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, gnome, metacity

I use semi-maximize a lot but unfortunately this feature doesn't seem to be enabled in gnome metacity, at least not with the usual <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> keybinds. It does work in Compiz, but Compiz gives me system errors on my laptop for some reason.

Is there a way to add this feature in metacity?

Comment: This should work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/568716/ubuntu-14-10-aero-snap-in-two-screen-horizontal-setup. Although the question is different, it works just the same on a single screen. Please let me know if you manage.

Comment: @JacobVlijm The script does indeed work correctly, but for some reason I'm not able to add a keyboard shortcut to the command. Here's a screenshot of my shortcut settings: [Shortcut settings](http://i.imgur.com/X0s64eA.png)
The whole command is `python3 $HOME/Scripts/aero.py right`

Comment: Please replace $HOME by the absolute path, then it should work.