# Shortcut for windows resizing and placement

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, display, resize, window-placement

I use two wide monitors for working and I find very useful using the edge screen for resizing and placing my windows (I just drag my windows to the left edge and it is resized and placed in the left half of the monitor)

This way I can visualize 4 windows at the same time which is great.

However I don't like having to manually resize the windows by dragging them to the desired edge.

I would really love if I can use a shortcut "eg Ctrl+[1,2,3,4]" to automatically resize and place the current window to the desired half of the monitor.

Eg: Ctrl + (1: 1st monitor left half, 2: left monitor right half, 3: right monitor left half, 4: right monitor right half).

Please tell me there is a way of doing this :)

Comment: Solutions posted in http://askubuntu.com/questions/116744/restore-the-ctrl-alt-num-pad-4-and-6-window-positioning-commands might help. Though not sure if it will work for multiple monitors (Here's more on that http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/ubuntu-multi-monitor-tweaks-full-screen.html)

Comment: You might like this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/709417/72216

Answer (score 3):

Such shortcuts already exist in default Ubuntu with Unity desktop:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> for right half of screen
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>  for left half of screen

They are part of compiz's grid plugin. If you find that these shortcuts stop working suddenly, install `compizconfig-settings-manager` and make sure you have `grid` checked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually not using Unity (XFCE instead) but there's a similar tool where I can assign a shortcut to place the windows in the left or right edge of the screen. However it only works for the screen where the window is. I cannot send the window to the other screen edges, unless I manually drag it.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki  default functionality of all desktops is such that they work with one screen only.  For future, please tag your questions with appropriate desktop tag

Comment: As for functionality of making it work with multiple screens, see the post Jacob suggested. Your question is thus a duplicate