# Can I move semi-maximized windows through multiple monitors?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, compiz

The "Grid" placement plugin in Compiz/Unity seems to mostly work like Windows' window management, in that I can bind <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> to place on the right half of the display, etc.  But, with more than one display, I ran into a difference in behavior from Windows:

Say you have a system with two displays side-by-side.  In Windows, if you have a window positioned (for example)  on the **right** half of the **left** display, and press <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>, the window moves to the **left** half of the **right** display.  That is, Windows considers the display layout as one big grid, and the shortcut keys can move the windows across displays.  This doesn't seem possible in Compiz?  (I know you can use different hotkeys to move between displays, but that's not what I'm asking for here)

Comment: If I am correct, this: http://askubuntu.com/a/709417/72216 is what you want. It is a few years ago, please test and let me know.

Comment: P.S. (re-) tested the script, works still fine here on 16.04