# Tile and move window across displays with keyboard (Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, tiling

I have two monitors: display L on the left, display R on the right. My current window is in the centre of L. I have configured the Super+Right shortcut to tile it to the right of L. That works fine.

Now I'd like <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to tile my window to the left or R. Unfortunately it stays stuck on the right of L.

Basically I'd like it to work like Windows 10 which is very convenient and fast. You keep pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to move from one half to the next half on the right within **then across displays**.

**Is there any way in Xubuntu to configure <kbd>Super</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd>/<kbd>Left</kbd> to tile my window to the next display when it has reached the one end on one display?**

It's important for me that I'm using **the same shortcut**. I'm not interested in solutions where I have to use another shortcut to move my window to another display.

Comment: I know you aren't interested, but the others may be. The shortcut is Ctrl + Alt + NumPad 3. To jump from L to R and Ctrl + Alt + Numpad 1 from R to L.

Comment: Tested on Gnome, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work on other window managers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/568716/ubuntu-14-10-aero-snap-in-two-screen-horizontal-setup/572052#572052 Except for Unity, then use: http://askubuntu.com/a/709417/72216

Comment: @JacobVlijm : Thanks. I've tried your script and it looks like it would do what I need but it's a bit buggy. Mainly: the window is too tall after resizing (overlap the panel) and the window gets stuck on the edge of the screen _sometimes_, without moving to the next screen.

Comment: @user3748764 which of the two did you use? I suppose the gnome- version (which is the oldest). I consider the last (newest one) a better one, but is for Unity specifically. I'll see if I can find the time to alter and edit it on xfce (need to install it on one of my systems). Probably would be interesting to get it working properly on all window managers.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: I've also tried the second script now. It's also kind of working but with other bugs: left doesn't work across screens (might be related to the launcher width, I set it to 0 because). Right works most of the time but sometimes make the window very small or requires a second call to do what it should.

Comment: I can assure you the second one will only wotk well on Unity :)